# Listview Selection

Tags: c#

HI,

I need to select a single item(cell) in a listview

Comment: Are you asking how to select a single subitem in a row (and not the entire row) in the details mode of a listview?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot select 'subitems' in a ListView.  If you want to be able to select 'cells', you'll have to use a gridview.

Answer (score 1):

I developed a third-party component called [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview), that allows selecting sub-items with arrow keys.

It is also possible to label edit sub-items, use icons in them and such.

If you need to use sub-items as cells extensively, the grid-like controls are the best choice for you, since these are better designed for *matrices*, instead of *lists*.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't possible to select a single cell but it is possible to REFER to a single cell's value. The link below has an answer for that(getting of a value for a cell).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx

```
     // Uses the SelectedItems property to retrieve and tally the price 
     // of the selected menu items.

private void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged_UsingItems(
    object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection breakfast = 
        this.ListView1.SelectedItems;

    double price = 0.0;
    foreach ( ListViewItem item in breakfast )
    {
        price += Double.Parse(item.SubItems[1].Text);
    }

    // Output the price to TextBox1.
    TextBox1.Text = price.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code causes all the items in a list view to not be selected, then it causes item #2 to be selected. I'm sure you can easily adapt this code to your problem. By the way, list view items use zero-based indexing; therefore, item #2 is actually the third item in the list view.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            listView1.Items[i].Selected = false;
        }

        // select item #2
        listView1.Items[2].Selected = true;
```